# PyQt: Wait until widget closes

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a window/widget that shows after I press a button, is there a way to make the main window wait until the widget closes out? I am using `.show()` right now and I have tried using `.exec_()` already but it gives me this error:

`AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'exec_'`

Any help?

Comment: I think you want a modal dialog  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917339/qt-modal-dialog-and-main-process

Answer (score 4):

Use a [local event-loop](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qeventloop.html) to wait until the window/widget closes:

```
widget = QWidget()
widget.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
widget.show()
loop = QEventLoop()
widget.destroyed.connect(loop.quit)
loop.exec() # wait ...
print('finished')
```

To also block interaction with other windows, set the [window modality](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowModality-prop):

```
widget.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)
```

or for top-level windows with a parent:

```
window.setWindowModality(Qt.WindowModal)
```

Of course, if you can change the window/widget to a `QDialog`, then none of the above is necessary, since the same functionality is provided by [exec](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec):

```
widget = QDialog()
widget.exec() # wait ...
```